# angular2 how to get queryparams after refresh page once used fill search form?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs5

When I submit a search form, The url query params will changed.

And when I refresh the page, I want get the queryparams, autocompleted the search forms.

But I do not want Subscribe the changed, because I want get it only once.

This is my search model:

```
constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
){
    this.searchForms = this.formBuilder.group({
        cardId: [],
        cardType: [],
        beginTime: [],
        endTime: []
    });

    // this.activatedRoute.queryParams.getValue() 
    // I want use getValue method, But it throw a error msg:
    // "Property 'getValue' does not exist on type 'Observable<Params>'"
    // I do not know this method is correct.
    // Or have ohter better implementations.
    // And when i get queryparams, how to set the search model?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the first event only using `first`. And the `subscribe` callback will be called only once:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.first().subscribe(params => {
    // do something
})
```